# How do I address the issue of System program problem detected?

Tags: 13.10, startup

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 32-bit with Intel Core i5-3210M CPU @ 2.50GHz × 4 and keep receiving the message

> System program problem detected

at startup.

This is a recent installation. I'm new to Ubuntu and still learning what's inside. What can I do to address this error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to view the error report go to the `/var/crash/` directory and there you will find the error reports which you can view with any text editor.

If you can't figure out the problem and the message keeps coming up:

- It is possible that this error only happened once, but the error report got stuck and pops-up on every boot. So just delete the error reports from `/var/crash/` (you will need root privileges for some, so use the `sudo rm /var/crash/*` command). If after this the error message doesn't come back then all is good.
- If the error message is not from a stuck report, but the errors are constantly happening and you can't figure out the problem on your own then submit a bugreport. See [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)